# Mostrar Imagen desde un servidor remoto PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

Que tal amigos mi problema es el siguiente.

Tengo un Servidor A donde tengo imagenes, Tengo un servidor B el cual es el servidor de las aplicaciones, ambos servidores están conectados a una red y el serVidor A tiene una carpeta compartida con el servidor B con la letra V:

Si yo quiero mostrar una foto en mi explorador acceso así:

```
$ubicacion = 'V:/Fotos/imagen.jpg';
$content = file_get_contents($ubicacion);
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
echo $content;
```

No se si sea problemas de permisos del servidor A o haya una forma de desplegar la foto y guardarla en el servidor B

Comment: Nose si tener una carpeta compartida entre servidores sea la mejor opción. Creo que la mejor opción sería tener un servidor de archivos.

Comment: Es lo mismo que yo creo Arnold, por desgracia así tienen estructurada su red en este lugar :(

Answer (score 1):

La foto que intentas mostrar si es que esta exactamente como dejas el codigo no va a funcionar ya que es la ruta FISICA (`V:/Fotos/imagen.jpg`) ya que estas en distintos servidores. Lo que tienes que obtener es la URL de la imagen, deberia ser algo como `https://tuservidor.com/fotos/imagen.jpg`

Yo tengo el mismo funcionamiento que describes, lo que puedes hacer :

- En la base de datos del servidor, en una tabla Config tengo una columna que es URL_Images.
- Dentro de tu proyecto, en el archivo Config tengas una variable con el valor de la URL.

En el servidor B que es de donde consumes los datos, tu deberias armar la URL

```
$url_images = $this->config->item('url_imagen');
$imagen = $url_images + $imagen_mostrar;
```